# Filter gridview datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, filter, code-behind

I wan't to be able to search through my gridview result using code-behind.

I have a button and a gridview:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaperId" Width="146" runat="server"  />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" OnClick="FilterResult"/>

<asp:GridView ID="gvwResavePositions" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Positions found!"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="50" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SkinID="gridviewGridlinesSkin" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvwResavePositions_PageIndexChanged"
    HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100%">
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="DarkGray" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="left"  />
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-Width="40px" DataField="strPaperId" HeaderText="K+Id / PaperId" ReadOnly="True"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resave">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="bResave" runat="server" Width="50"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

My code behind:

```
protected void FilterResult(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        (gvwResavePositions.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("strPaperId = '{0}'",
            txtPaperId.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var t = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

When I press "Search" button I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The objectdatasource is set before the search button is pressed (it's another button...), so when FilterResult is going the gridview is full of results..

Do you have any tip how I can do this?

***EDIT***

Solved it. It was because my datasource was null, so I had to rebind it.

Comment: where is txtPaperId???

Comment: Forgot to paste that in...1 sec

Comment: i posted answer try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// save your datatable in session while binding gridview
    // Session["Dt_GridView"]=Your_datatable; 
    protected void FilterResult(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           // DataTable dt = (DataTable)gvwResavePositions.DataSource; this reutrn null
            // hence
            //gvwResavePositions.DataSource as DataTable this will return null



            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Dt_GridView"];

         dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("strPaperId = '{0}'",
                txtPaperId.Text);
         gvwResavePositions.DataSource = dt;
          gvwResavePositions.DataBind();
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var t = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Next question: Is it possible to search on several strPaperId?

Comment: You want to search again and Again??

Comment: No, strPaperId IN (id1, id2, id3)

Comment: then what you will wrote in textbox you can use IN clause LIKE `strPaperId IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3') `

Comment: In my textbox: "id1,id2,id3". But when using 'strPaperId In {0}' that is not working for me..Like it is not seperating the ID's by the comma

Comment: @krillezzz you could manually make a string that contains "ID1 AND ID2 AND".
You just make a for-loop and add them to the string one by one with they keyword AND between the ID's. But I would still go for the dataview rowfilter :).

Comment: beacuse when we exec sql query that looks like `select * from table where col in ('id1','id2','id3')` beacuse id1 is string so you should provide same ways like this `strPaperId IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')`

Comment: @krillezzz Just look at this many no of Examples available http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [dataview rowfilter.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Update: you must use the [correct parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy5b8exc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
With the rowfilter it is also possible to filter on already filtered items (it was your next question).

Or there also this possibility:

```
string strWhere = string.empty
foreach (string id in ids)
{
string += id + " OR " 
}

string += 0
```

Comment: When using .AsDataView.RowFilter I get "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: table". But txtPaperId.Text is not null?